# Multitenant site (multisite) with NextJs and catch all routes

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, url-rewriting, seo

I have many sites(domains), that are serving same products with different domains and urls. All domains have different designs of header, footer, product cards, etc...

```
site1.com
site1-[city].com - 100 different cities and domains
site2.com
site2-[city].com - 100 different cities and domains
site3-site3.com
site3-site3-[city].com - 100 different cities and domains
```

All that domains have different slugs for same products. For example same chair can have different urls at the end:

```
site1.com/[category]/[subcategory]/chair
site1-[city].com.com/chair
site1-[city].com/[category]/chair
```

Can i make 1 frontend application with NextJs so that, when user comes to a page

```
site1.com/[category]/[subcategory]/chair
```

he is transfered by some server to NextJs application that builds him specific page. And when anoter user goes to

```
site1-[city].com.com/chair
```

he is then sent to the same nextjs app, that gives him another page. Can i use 1 dynamic page with catch all routes?